# discounted price is a martingale under any measure?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Assume I have some dynamics for the stock price under 2 different measures: risk-neutral and forward measures: 
$$dS_t=r S_tdt+\sigma S_td\tilde{W_t}$$
$$dS_t=\alpha S_tdt+\sigma S_td\hat{W_t}$$

now I define 2 functions:
$$g(t,s)=\mathbb{\tilde{E}}[e^{-\int_t^Tr_udu}h(S(T))|\mathbb{F}_t]$$
$$f(t,s)=\mathbb{\hat{E}}[e^{-\int_t^Tr_udu}h(S(T))|\mathbb{F}_t]$$
Then in both cases $e^{-\int_0^tr_udu}g$ and $e^{-\int_0^tr_udu}f$ are martingales under $\tilde{\mathbb{P}}$ and $\hat{\mathbb{P}}$ respectively. In the first case, it is basically discounting with a bank account, which(using tower property) is RN measure associated with. In the second though, the measure is associated with the bond of maturity $T$ so I would expectt $f/B(t,T)$ be a martingale under $\hat{\mathbb{P}}$, but I see $e^{-\int_0^tr_udu}f$ is. So they both are?

Comment: For constant, or deterministic, interest rate, the risk-neutral measure and the forward measure are the same, and any martingality property is also the same. They will be different under the stochastic interest rate assumption.

Comment: @Gordon: I edited the question as I did not mean the trivial case. I sort of guess that $g$ is the price of a derivative while $f$ is not, and rather just a ``function" and doesn't have to have the property of $f/B$ be a martingale, but would be nice if someone can clarify this precisely.

Comment: The notations for  $e^{-rt}f$ and $e^{-rt}$ are still confusing unless $r$ is a constant. You are right that $g$ is a pricing function, while $f$ is not.

Comment: @Gordon: Thanks, edited all of the terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, based on your definition, $e^{-\int_0^tr_s ds}f$ is a martingale under the forward measure $\hat{\Bbb{P}}$. Note that, since $f$ is not an asset price process, $f/B(t, T)$ is not a martingale process under $\hat{\Bbb{P}}$.

Since $g$ is an asset price process, then $e^{-\int_0^tr_s ds}g$ is a martingale under the risk-neutral measure $\tilde{\Bbb{P}}$. Moreover, $g/B(t, T)$ is a  martingale under the forward measure $\hat{\Bbb{P}}$. In fact, note that
\begin{align*}
\eta_t =: \frac{d\tilde{\Bbb{P}}}{d\hat{\Bbb{P}}}|_t = \frac{B(0, T) e^{\int_0^t r_s ds}}{B(t, T)}.
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
g(t, S) &= \tilde{\Bbb{E}}\left(e^{-\int_t^T r_s ds} h(S_T) \mid \mathscr{F}_t \right)\\
&=\hat{\Bbb{E}}\left(\frac{\eta_T}{\eta_t} e^{-\int_t^T r_s ds} h(S_T) \mid \mathscr{F}_t \right)\\
&= B(t, T)\hat{\Bbb{E}}\left(h(S_T) \mid \mathscr{F}_t \right).
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\frac{g(t, S)}{B(t, T)} = \hat{\Bbb{E}}\left(h(S_T) \mid \mathscr{F}_t \right)
\end{align*}
is a martingale.

Your definition of $f$ is just a conditional expectation, which does not have any financial meaning. Alternatively, you can define $f$ by
\begin{align*}
f(t, S) =B(t, T)\hat{\Bbb{E}}\left(h(S_T) \mid \mathscr{F}_t \right),
\end{align*}
but then $f(t, S)=g(t, S)$.

Comment: Crystal clear answer, +1